# Running vagrant up in Homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to get Laravel Homestead set up on my mac.  I am at the part where I run `vagrant up` and this is the error message I am receiving:

> ==> homestead-7: Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: Unit php7.0-fpm.service not found.
>
> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
>   should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should upgrade your entire homestead installation. `cd ~/Homestead && git pull && vagrant destroy && vagrant box update && vagrant up
` Upgrade & Provision your homestead box.

Comment: Thank you @Kirk. It worked? Here's the final output after running the command you suggested:
`==> homestead-7: Updating to version 1.2.4 (stable channel).
==> homestead-7:     Downloading: Connecting...
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7:     Downloading: 100%
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7:
==> homestead-7: Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.2.3
==> homestead-7: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead-7: Running: /var/folders/pr/3bh8jmyj21n4b45xp8xzng2r0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20161208-22373-3clp89.sh
Josephs-MacBook-Pro:Homestead Joey$`

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting!

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the additional details. I'm not sure what is causing your problem, but good luck in solving it.

Comment: What happens if you run `homestead up` now?

Comment: `Josephs-MacBook-Pro:Homestead Joey$ homestead up


-bash: homestead: command not found


Josephs-MacBook-Pro:Homestead Joey$`

Answer (score 0):

Share on your folders files with "7.1" and change it to "5.0"